# How to I diagnose downloads slowing over time?

Tags: linux, redhat, tomcat, http, tcpip

I am trying to track down a strange networking problem.

Basically, a http download from a tomcat server is slowing down over time. For example, the download speed starts at 700kb, then slows to 650, 600, 550, 500, etc.

I have heard TCP/IP windowing might cause this problem. To make this problem a little stranger sFTP does not see the speed decrease.

I am confident it is not a problem with the webapp. It is running from tomcat and a Linux red hat machine.

Go easy on me, I am not a network guy.

GC_

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about your network and what http client you are using.

If you are using Tomcat to serve static files, that's not ideal from a performance standpoint (NGINX or Apache are better suited for this). If Tomcat is applying gzip compression or the app is generating the data being downloaded this could explain the behavior.

Comment: @Jeffrey This is just a basic servlet, that spits out lines.  I not really complaining about the speed.  I am complaining that the speed slows down.  There is no compression.

Comment: What is the output of curl --head http://url.com/path-to-servlet (this assumes a *nix environment). You could also copy the headers out of Chrome using developer tools if you're on Windows.

Comment: @Jeffrey What am I looking for?  (I don't think I will be able to publish this type of information.)